# How to navigate through elements in lxml?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Say I have element tree returned by xquery

```
categories = tree.xpath(u"//ul[@class='tree-root']/li")

for cat in categories:
    catName = cat.find('span/span') # is there any shortcut for this?
```

As you can see I use find in order to access span elements. The question is there any shortcut to access child elements with known path or find is the only way?

Comment: What would be shorter than a single call?

Comment: `find` sounds like doing some search work, affecting performance, whereas I certainly know the path and there is no need to search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xpath()` on elements the same way as on the tree:

```py
span = cat.xpath('span/span')
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything about more direct access to subelements in the docs. They can be iterated over or accessed as list elements, but that's not very handy. The `Element` class only provides access to the attributes of the current element.

Comment: I mean is there any way to natively access them like cat['span']['span'] or cat.span.span?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I've expanded the answer a little.

Comment: Too bad... anyway, спасибо :)